# Vecorizing an inner for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I would like to vectorize the inner loop in MATLAB of the folowing nested loop construction:

```
for j = 1:MM
    S4 = 0;
    for i = 1:MM            
        S4 = S4 + b(i,1)*func(i,x(j),0,1);
    end

    F(j) = u(j) - f(x(j))-S4;
end
```

where `b`, `F`, and `U` are vectors of length `MM`. Just want to optimize this segment for code.

Answer (score 3):

In order to vectorize the inner loop, you need to vectorize `func()` first (for the first argument only). I.e., `func` must be able to handle something like this:

```
func([1:MM], x(j), 0, 1)
```

If you can do this, then you can just use `sum` over the element-wise multiplication:

```
S4 = sum( b(:,1) .* func([1:MM], x(j), 0, 1) );
```